# SOS! SSRS parameters show different result with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am making a SSRS report with 4 dropdown list.All of them are added in query.
ID01,
ID02,
StartPeriod,
EndPeriod.

StartPeriod and EndPeriod are nvarchar, but they are showing the date. Like, 201401,201403.

My problem is when I run the SSRS, if I select all of ID01 and all of ID02, I cant get anything between 201401-201405. But there is record when i run SSMS. Everything after 201405 are no problem.

My code is

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE ABC

     @ID01 nvarchar(2000)
    ,@ID02 nvarchar(10)
    ,@StartPeriod nvarchar(30)
    ,@EndPeriod nvarchar(30)
    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT ID01,ID02

,CASE WHEN year(Date)='2014' and month (Date)='01'then '201401'

      WHEN year(Date)='2014' and month (Date)='02'then '201402'
                              .
                              .
                              .
      WHEN year(Date)='2015' and month (Date)='05'then '201505'

      END AS Period

INTO #tmp_ABC

FROM A

WHERE     ID01 IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.udf_ABC(@ID01,','))

      AND ID02 IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.udf_ABC(@ID02,',')) 
            (THIS TWO ARE DROP DOWN LIST FOR SSRS)

----------


SELECT ID01,ID02,Period

FROM #tmp_ABC

WHERE Period >= @StartPeriod AND Period <=@EndPeriod (DROP DOWN LIST FOR SSRS)

END
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my report? It is my first time using this. Forgive me if I wrote the wrong format...
Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason @ID02 is only 10 characters long? That doesn't leave much room for the parameter list. This could be an issue.

Your stored procedure seems overly complicated - not really the cause of your problem but can be simplified. Here is a re-working of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC
     @ID01 nvarchar(2000)
    ,@ID02 nvarchar(2000)
    ,@StartPeriod nvarchar(30)
    ,@EndPeriod nvarchar(30)
    AS
BEGIN

    SELECT ID01, ID02, 
      CAST(Year(Date) AS NVARCHAR) + Right('0' + CAST(Month(Date) AS NVARCHAR), 2) AS Period
    FROM A
    WHERE ID01 IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.udf_ABC(@ID01,','))
      AND ID02 IN (SELECT Param FROM dbo.udf_ABC(@ID02,',')) 
      AND CAST(Year(Date) AS NVARCHAR) + Right('0' + CAST(Month(Date) AS NVARCHAR), 2) >= @StartPeriod 
      AND CAST(Year(Date) AS NVARCHAR) + Right('0' + CAST(Month(Date) AS NVARCHAR), 2) <= @EndPeriod

END
```

Comment: If that solved your problem you should accept the answer so that other people know it was solved (an upvote is also appreciated :) )

Comment: Oh~!!Sorry for that, it is my first time using  this. I just accept the answer, but I don't have enough reputation for upvote....I will definitely upvote to you after I got enough reputation!!